# Under what conditions DQN selects only one action?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm implementing DQN in reinforcement learning, double DQN actually, and it's returning only one action, out of 7 possible actions. I've tried changing number of layers of neural network, regularization parameters, layer size. But I still get only one action. That is, for a particular set of parameters, I get only one action. I wanted to know if it is a common scenario. What it would imply and under what conditions we will encounter such situation? Any suggestion for resolving this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies on how you implemented everything(please show us the code), but these are some possibilities:

- a bug in the program
- initial weights are not so good
- state-action values are infinity/NaN

I think you should check your state-action values and verify that they're not diverging to infinity/NaN, because that's most likely the case.

Comment: As you suggested, Q values were very high...  10^22! When I searched for reason, i realized that i had one input value which was very high, and it caused very high Q values, in turn resulting only one action. Once I removed that input (which was strictly not needed anyway), I got the things running smoothly with different actions as output. Your suggestions indeed helped!!

Comment: @StatMan Awesome to know that helped!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you come up with these suggestions?

Comment: @StatMan I've recently had the exact same problem. Turns out that DQN, or Q Learning in general tends to diverge when the function approximation is non-linear, as in most cases. I guess experience pays off!

Comment: Learning by Experience pays off not just for machines but humans as well. Amen!